# How to create multiple executables or libraries from a list of names in a Makefile

Tags: build, makefile

I want to build a set of executables or libraries from a list of names. They all build the same way and basically need two files that are lexiograhically connected:

```
X.exe : X.o X_y.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

In my makefile I want to just list all my X:s and automatically build all the .exe's. So from

```
Xs : a b c
```

I want the Makefile to execute as if I had written the rules

```
a.exe : a.o a_y.o
b.exe : b.o b_y.o
c.exe : c.o c_y.o
```

Of course this is to simplify adding another X.

My basic problem seems to be that the definition of Xs above is a set of names and I need to break that up into separate rules. I know about patterns and have tried to use the foreach text function, but failed.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pattern rules is the way to go:

```
Xs=a b c

default: $(patsubst %,%.exe,$(Xs))

%.exe : %.o %_y.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Prerequisites of a pattern rule can use `%` several times.

Note that you don't need to use `foreach`. Simply tell `make` all the targets you want to build.